# My content is above my header?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, header, footer

So I'm trying to do a simple header content footer page, withouth spaces between the divs and on the left and right, I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="divHeader">
    </div>

    <div id="divContent">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>


    <div id="divFooter">
    </div>
```

and this is my CSS code:

```
    #divHeader
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 68px;
    background-color:#1C1C1C;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;    
}

#divContent
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:red; 
}

#divFooter
{
    width:100%;
    min-height:250px;
    background-color:#1C1C1C;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

With this code I can see the footer exactly how I want it, but I cant see the header because the content its above it.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css propriety `z-index:1;` on the `#divHeader` element in this way the header will be in front like a layer.